# How do I import a constructed object from javascript into typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I am using a javascript library that constructs an object like so:

usefulJS.js

```
function usefulJS() {}

usefulJS.protoype.doAThing = function() {
    //does a thing here, returns an object
};
module.exports = new usefulJS();
```

It has a type definition file like so:

usefulJS/index.d.ts

```js
export class usefulJS {
    public doAThing(): object;
}
```

And it is used in the following typescript file:

myTypescript.ts

```js
import {randomOtherThing,usefulJS} from "library-that-includes-usefulJS";

const myObj = usefulJS.doAThing();
```

But I get a red underline under .doAThing() in my typescript file with the following message:

"Property 'doAThing' does not exist on type 'typeof usefulJS'."

When I run the code with `//@ts-ignore` over the function call it works, so it definitely seem to be a typescript issue and not a javascript issue.

Am I doing something wrong with my imports? How should I import an object that is already constructed, as opposed to a prototype for an object?

Or is there something wrong with the library's type definitions?

If it is any help, there is another project in non-typescript node that uses this library. Its import line looks like this:

```
const usefulJS = requre("library-that-includes-usefulJS").usefulJS;
```

Comment: remove the curlys from your import statement.

Comment: Hmm. That won't be possible for some details that I left out (I am actually importing from a larger library that includes usefulJS.js). I will add that detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to change the library that solves the problem without making any of the existing javascript clients change their code.

Basically, by changing the library to export a type with static functions instead of an unnamed object with object functions, typescript stops complaining about being unable to call the method and the javascript calls to the library don't change at all.

(usefulJS.doAThing() with usefulJS as an object calling its prototype function changes to usefulJS.doAThing() as a type calling its static function, with javascript not caring about the difference.)

usefulJS.js

```
class usefulJS() {

    static doAThing()  {
    //does a thing here, returns an object
    };
}
//Returns a type with a static method instead of a constructed object
module.exports = usefulJS;
```

usefulJS/index.d.ts

```js
export class usefulJS {
    public static doAThing(): object;
}
```

myTypescript.ts

```js
import {randomOtherThing,usefulJS} from "library-that-includes-usefulJS";

const myObj = usefulJS.doAThing();
```

Still doesn't help much for those who don't have control over the library, unfortunately, but at least we don't cause exploding changes to all the javascript clients that already worked just to make typescript clients work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: TypeScript probably locate `usefulJS` from usefulJS.js instead of index.d.ts (you can check if that's the case by using "go to definition" in VS Code). If that's the case TypeScript will not recognize that usefulJS has a `doAThing` method, because it is assigned through prototype. You can probably solve this by adding this to your tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "library-that-includes-usefulJS": [
            "./usefulJS/index.d.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about tsconfig. Didn't seem to be the problem this time, but I have had some weird problems before where tsconfig was ultimately at fault.

Answer (score 0):

By making library changes I am able to get it to work.

Basically, the index.d.ts file doesn't indicate that helpfulJS.js exports a value. Unfortunately, we can't indicate that it exports the value helpfulJS, because that would result in a name overlap with the type. So helpfulJS.js needs to be modified to export a different variable name.

usefulJS.js

```
function usefulJS() {}

usefulJS.protoype.doAThing = function() {
    //does a thing here, returns an object
};
let usefulJSObj = new usefulJS();
module.exports = usefulJSObj;
```

usefulJS/index.d.ts

```js
export class usefulJS {
    public doAThing(): object;
}

export const usefulJSObj : usefulJS;
```

myTypescript.ts

```js
import {randomOtherThing,usefulJSObj} from "library-that-includes-usefulJS";

const myObj = usefulJSObj.doAThing();
```

I do have the ability to change this library in this case but I am loath to do so because it has impact on other projects.

I am still hoping there is a way to fix this without changing the library (or maybe only changing the type file, since the other users of the library are javascript).